# Error with CTkMessagebox (TypeError: 'str' object is not callable)

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

**CONTEXT**
I programmed a hangman game on python and used "tkinter" for its GUI. It works perfectly.
I switched from tkinter to "customtkinter" and "CTkMessagebox" to have a GUI with a better visual, eveyrthin works perfectly except one thing.

**PROBLEM**
When my program check the entry of the user (to make sure it's a letter without an accent or a cedilla), a message box with an error message pops up if the entry is incorrect.
But with CTkMessagebox nothin I receive the following error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\thiba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1948, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\thiba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 554, in _clicked
> self._command()
> File "c:\Users\thiba\OneDrive\Documents\Studies\Programming\Python\Hangman\Hangman (with customtkinter)", line 32, in game
> CTkMessagebox(master=root, title="Entry error", message="Only letters (without an accent or a cedilla) can be entered.", icon="warning")
> File "C:\Users\thiba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\CTkMessagebox\ctkmessagebox.py", line 57, in **init**
> super().**init**()
> File "C:\Users\thiba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\ctk_toplevel.py", line 36, in **init**
> super().**init**(*args, **pop_from_dict_by_set(kwargs, self.*valid_tk_toplevel_arguments))
> File "C:\Users\thiba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter_*init**.py", line 2681, in **init**
> self.title(root.title())
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

**WHAT I TRIED**

- I made a another small program with CTkMessagebox and it worked
- I put the line concerning the message box somewhere else in the code but the problem is the same

**Here is my code**

```
from Dictionary import dico
from Drawings import drawings

import random
import customtkinter as CTk
from CTkMessagebox import CTkMessagebox

word_guess = dico[random.randrange(len(dico) - 1)]
word_hidden = " _" * len(word_guess)
drawing_nb = 0
tries = 0
list = []
print(word_guess)





#------------------------------- GAME LOOP -------------------------------#
def game(*args):
    global word_guess
    global word_hidden
    global tries
    global drawings
    global drawing_nb

    letter_tried = f2_var_LetterTried.get().lower()
    letters_tried = f2_var_LettersTried.get()

    # Check the entry
    if not (letter_tried.isalpha() and letter_tried.isascii()):
        CTkMessagebox(master=root, title="Entry error", message="Only letters (without an accent or a cedilla) can be entered.", icon="warning")
        return
    
    # Check if the word/letter has already been tried
    for string in list:
        if letter_tried == string:
            f2_ent_WordEntry.delete(0, CTk.END)
            return

    tries +=1

    # For a letter
    if len(letter_tried) == 1:
        # Check if the letter has already been tried
        for string in list:
            if letter_tried == string:
                f2_ent_WordEntry.delete(0, CTk.END)
                return

        if letter_tried not in (word_guess or word_hidden):
            drawing_nb += 1
            f2_var_drawing.set(drawings[drawing_nb])
            if letters_tried == "":
                letters_tried += letter_tried
                f2_var_LettersTried.set(letters_tried)
            else:
                letters_tried += ", " + letter_tried
                f2_var_LettersTried.set(letters_tried)
        else:
            letter_pos = 1
            for char in word_guess:
                if letter_tried == char:
                    word_hidden = word_hidden[:letter_pos * 2 - 1] + letter_tried + word_hidden[letter_pos * 2:]
                letter_pos += 1
            f2_var_WordHidden.set(word_hidden)

    # For a word
    # Check if the word has already been tried
    for string in list:
        if letter_tried == string:
            f2_ent_WordEntry.delete(0, CTk.END)
            return

    if len(letter_tried) >1:
        if letter_tried == word_guess:
            end_game(f'Congratulations, you have found the word "{word_guess}"" in {tries} tries!')
            return
        else:
            drawing_nb += 1
            f2_var_drawing.set(drawings[drawing_nb])
            if letters_tried == "":
                letters_tried += letter_tried
                f2_var_LettersTried.set(letters_tried)
            else:
                letters_tried += ", " + letter_tried
                f2_var_LettersTried.set(letters_tried)
    
    if "_" not in word_hidden:
        end_game(f"Congratulations, you have found the word {word_guess} in {tries} tries!")
        return

    if drawing_nb == 10:
        end_game(f'Game Over, the word was "{word_guess}".')
    
    list.append(letter_tried)
    f2_ent_WordEntry.delete(0, CTk.END)





#------------------------------- CHANGING FRAME -------------------------------#
def first_game():
    root.bind("<Return>", game)
    f2_ent_WordEntry.focus()
    frame2.tkraise()

def end_game(message):
    global drawings
    global drawing_nb 
    f3_lb_EndMessage.configure(text=message)
    f3_lb_drawing.configure(text=drawings[drawing_nb])
    root.bind("<Return>","")
    frame3.tkraise()

def new_game():
    global word_guess
    global word_hidden
    global tries
    global drawings
    global drawing_nb
    global f2_var_LettersTried
    global list

    word_guess = dico[random.randrange(len(dico) - 1)]
    word_hidden = " _" * len(word_guess)
    drawing_nb = 0
    tries = 0
    list = []

    f2_var_LettersTried.set("")
    f2_var_WordHidden.set(word_hidden)
    f2_var_drawing.set(drawings[drawing_nb])

    f2_ent_WordEntry.delete(0, CTk.END)
    f2_ent_WordEntry.focus()
    root.bind("<Return>", game)
    frame2.tkraise()
    print(word_guess)





#------------------------------- START WINDOW -------------------------------#
# Create main application window
root = CTk.CTk()
root.title = "The Hangman"
root.geometry("750x300")

# Create 1ST frame2
frame1 = CTk.CTkFrame(root)
frame1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="news")

# Label for drawings
f1_lb_hangman = CTk.CTkLabel(frame1, text=drawings[10], font=("Consolas", 12), justify="left")
f1_lb_hangman.grid(column=0, row=0, rowspan=4)

# Label for title
f1_lb_title = CTk.CTkLabel(frame1, text="THE HANGMAN", font=("Consolas", 20))
f1_lb_title.grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=2)

# Label for signature
f1_lb_signature = CTk.CTkLabel(frame1, text="By T.D.", font=('Consolas', 9))
f1_lb_signature.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="n")

# Button for starting a game
f1_btn_start = CTk.CTkButton(frame1, text="Start a game", command=first_game)
f1_btn_start.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2)





#------------------------------- IN-GAME WINDOW -------------------------------#
# Create 2ND frame
frame2 = CTk.CTkFrame(root)
frame2.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="news")

# Label for drawings
f2_var_drawing = CTk.StringVar()
f2_var_drawing.set(drawings[drawing_nb])
f2_lb_drawing = CTk.CTkLabel(frame2, textvariable=f2_var_drawing, font=("Consolas", 12), justify="left")
f2_lb_drawing.grid(column=0, row=0, rowspan=4)

# Label for title
f2_lb_title = CTk.CTkLabel(frame2, text="THE HANGMAN", font=("Consolas", 20))
f2_lb_title.grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=2)

# Label for signature
f2_lb_signature = CTk.CTkLabel(frame2, text="By Thibaud D.", font=('Consolas', 9))
f2_lb_signature.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="n")

# Label for hidden word
f2_var_WordHidden = CTk.StringVar()
f2_var_WordHidden.set(word_hidden)
f2_lb_WordHidden = CTk.CTkLabel(frame2, textvariable=f2_var_WordHidden, font=("Consolas", 12), wraplength=500)
f2_lb_WordHidden.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=500)

# Labels for letters tried
f2_var_LettersTried = CTk.StringVar()
f2_lb_LettersTried = CTk.CTkLabel(frame2, textvariable=f2_var_LettersTried, font=("Consolas", 12), justify="left")
f2_lb_LettersTried.grid(column=2, row=3)
CTk.CTkLabel(frame2, text="Previous tries:", font=("Consolas", 12), justify="right").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky="e")

# Entry to try letter/word
f2_var_LetterTried = CTk.StringVar()
f2_ent_WordEntry = CTk.CTkEntry(frame2, textvariable=f2_var_LetterTried)
f2_ent_WordEntry.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky="w")

# Button to try entry
f2_btn_try = CTk.CTkButton(frame2, text="Try", command=game)
f2_btn_try.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky="w")





#------------------------------- END-GAME WINDOW -------------------------------#
# Create 3RD frame
frame3 = CTk.CTkFrame(root)
frame3.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="news")

# Label for drawings
f3_lb_drawing = CTk.CTkLabel(frame3, font=("Consolas", 12), justify="left")
f3_lb_drawing.grid(column=0, row=0, rowspan=4)

# Label for title
f3_lb_title = CTk.CTkLabel(frame3, text="THE HANGMAN", font=("Consolas", 20))
f3_lb_title.grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=2)

# Label for signature
f3_lb_signature = CTk.CTkLabel(frame3, text="By Thibaud D.", font=('Consolas', 9))
f3_lb_signature.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="n")

# Label for end message
f3_lb_EndMessage = CTk.CTkLabel(frame3, font=("Consolas", 12), wraplength=500, justify="left")
f3_lb_EndMessage.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=500)

# Labels for letters tried
f3_lb_LettersTried = CTk.CTkLabel(frame3, textvariable=f2_var_LettersTried, font=("Consolas", 12), justify="left", )
f3_lb_LettersTried.grid(column=2, row=3)
CTk.CTkLabel(frame3, text="Previous tries:", font=("Consolas", 12), justify="right").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky="e")

# Button to try entry
button_try = CTk.CTkButton(frame3, text="Start a new game", command=new_game)
button_try.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky="w")





frame1.tkraise()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have override the `title()` function by the following line:

```py
root.title = "The Hangman"
```

So when tkinter calls `root.title()` internally, it raises exception.

Change the problem line to:

```py
root.title("The Hangman")
```

Comment: Thanks, you've solved my problem!